# How to make AdMob Mediation stop showing Ads from AdMob and force use other networks?

Tags: admob, unityads, mobile-ad-mediation

Am making a game and the client said that when he get a reward Ad from UnityAds the reward callback are not executing properly, i need to test that but i can't because i am exclusivly getting Ads from AdMob even thought that our mediation group contain UnityAds, Vungle and Nend, is there a way to force another network to show ? i tried lowering the eCPM of AdMob to $0.01 and keeping others in $10 but i still get AdMob only.

Any help please ?

PS:
me and my clients are in different countries, probably this is why he get unityAds and i almost never did.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Locate your ad unit ID in the [AdMob UI](https://apps.admob.com), and open its mediation settings (the screen where you add networks). On the far right, you should see a link for "Country-specific settings." Open that link for each network *except* Unity Ads, then use the controls in the dialog to limit each one so that it only serves in Antarctica.

After that, save your changes and wait about an hour. You should start seeing Unity Ads 100% of the time. Unless you're running the app in Antarctica, of course. :)

**EDIT:** If you're using mediation groups, you actually have [more control](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7374967) over your mediation settings. You can make a second, temporary mediation group with just Unity Ads that also targets your ad unit, and then pause the original mediation group. When you're finished testing, pause the second group and unpause the first, and you're back to normal.

Comment: Thank you but are you sure this is up to day ? cause the only thing that i can edit after adding a network is their ePCM : https://i.imgur.com/qv2TrkX.png

Comment: Ah, you're using mediation groups. I've updated my answer with some advice for configuring them.

Comment: PS: this is a bit off-topic but can you please take a look at this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/game-engines/bQpXD9rFr4Q ? my game is made with a Japanese publisher and they want Nend in there, and honestly there isn't enough information on how to implement that network with unity, thanks!

Comment: As coincidence would have it, I did the final review for our Unity guide for nend today. It'll show up at https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation in a week or so. In the meantime, you can download our nend Unity package here: https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-unity/GoogleMobileAdsNendMediation. It should work as long as you import everything in it into Unity.

Comment: Great! i'll keep an eye on the documentation, i also really hope Nend improve their dashboard as its really a pain now to work with. PS: i imported the new package, used a mediation group that only has Nend, still nothing, though am not sure now what's wrong, it could be anything so am just gonna wait for the Documentation, Thanks a lot for the help man, really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't think it can works anymore as AdMob can't be removed from mediation group.